# Haskell List comprehension syntax

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm trying to understand Brent Yorgey's multiset partition algorithm in the [Monad.Reader Issue 8](https://wiki.haskell.org/wikiupload/d/dd/TMR-Issue8.pdf).  It's been a long time since I've written any Haskell, and I guess I've forgotten even basic stuff.  I'm stuck on the code in this listing:

[image]

I should tell you that `Vec` is a type alias for `[Int]`, and that `<|=` means componentwise comparison of vectors:

[image]

The function `withinFromTo` is supposed to return a list of nonnegative vectors componentwise `<= m`, and lexicographically between `s` and `e` (inclusive).

I'm stuck on the line:

```
[x:xs | x <- [start, (start-1)..end]
```

What does `[start, (start-1)..end]` mean?  I went to [tryhaskell.org](https://tryhaskell.org/) and tried evaluating `[3,2..7]` but it just gave me `[]`.

I know this must seem like a stupid question, but I haven't been able to find anything by Googling, and I feel like I could read the docs for a long time before running across this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[a, b .. c]` syntax is intended to make an arithmetic progression that starts with `a` and `b`, and continues until it hits `c`. It's probably simplest explained with a few examples:

```
> [3, 2 .. 0]
[3,2,1,0]
> [2, 4 .. 10]
[2,4,6,8,10]
> [3, 1 .. -10]
[3,1,-1,-3,-5,-7,-9]
```

The Haskell Report section on [Arithmetic Sequences](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-400003.10), together with the section on [the `Enum` type class](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1310006.3.4) have the full details:

> Arithmetic sequences satisfy these identities:
>
> ```
> [ e1.. ]      = enumFrom e1
> [ e1,e2.. ]   = enumFromThen e1 e2
> [ e1..e3 ]    = enumFromTo e1 e3
> [ e1,e2..e3 ] = enumFromThenTo e1 e2 e3
> ```
>
> where `enumFrom`, `enumFromThen`, `enumFromTo`, and `enumFromThenTo` are class methods in the class `Enum` as defined in the `Prelude` (see Figure 6.1).
>
> For the types `Int` and `Integer`, the enumeration functions have the following meaning:
>
> - The sequence `enumFrom e1` is the list [e1,e1 + 1,e1 + 2,…].
> - The sequence `enumFromThen e1 e2` is the list [e1,e1 + i,e1 + 2i,…], where the increment, `i`, is `e2 − e1`. The increment may be zero or negative. If the increment is zero, all the list elements are the same.
> - The sequence `enumFromTo e1 e3` is the list [e1,e1 + 1,e1 + 2,…e3]. The list is empty if `e1 > e3`.
> - The sequence `enumFromThenTo e1 e2 e3` is the list [e1,e1 + i,e1 + 2i,…e3], where the increment, `i`, is `e2 − e1`. If the increment is positive or zero, the list terminates when the next element would be greater than `e3`; the list is empty if `e1 > e3`. If the increment is negative, the list terminates when the next element would be less than `e3`; the list is empty if `e1 < e3`.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I recognize this now, but I can't imagine how I would ever have found it by myself.